# failed to push the branch to the remote repository

Tags: visual-studio, github

Hello I am trying to push an branch in visual studio there is an error :
[image]

When I tried the following windows is shown:

[image]

and

[image]

I have inserted my credentials but without success.

Is it other way o solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You might as well using the [git cli](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-The-Command-Line).

First you need to create an SSH Key.

--- Linux :

```bash
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "yourGitHubMail@youmail.com"
```

press 'Enter' a a couple of times
after that you should get a success message.
copy your id_rsa.pub

```bash
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

--- Windows :
Create folder if exists, and create SSH Key

```
mkdir /Users/username/.ssh && cd /Users/username/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "yourGitHubMail@youmail.com"
```

Copy the code was outputed.

Go to you github page and press 'Settings' => 'SSH and GPG Keys'
Click 'New SSH Key'
in the test area under 'Key', paste in your SSH key.

Answer (score 0):

You shoul generate an application password (access token) in GitHub and filling it in instead of your password and it will works ! Doc [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

Comment: I have created a token but now I can´t accesso as well. Can you help me?

Comment: You mean the GitHub web application ?

Comment: No, on visual studio I have the same issue I can to do push to git online.

Comment: Using HTTPS that's it ?

Comment: It seems working now. I just do it: Solution - Go to your GitHub account >> Profile >> Emails >> "Keep my email addresses private" - >> Uncheck this option.

Comment: Good job ! So you can close the issue :)